# Check if an object has changed

Tags: php

Is there a more native way (e.x. a built-in function) with less userland code to check if an objects property values have changed instead of using one of those methods:

**The serialize approach**

```
$obj = new stdClass(); // May be an instance of any class

echo $hashOld = md5(serialize($obj)) . PHP_EOL;

$obj->change = true;

echo $hashNew = md5(serialize($obj)) . PHP_EOL;

echo 'Changed: '; var_dump($hashOld !== $hashNew);
```

Which results in:

```
f7827bf44040a444ac855cd67adfb502 (initial)
506d1a0d96af3b9920a31ecfaca7fd26 (changed)
Changed: bool(true)
```

**The shadow copy approach**

```
$obj = new stdClass();
$shadowObj = clone $obj;

$obj->change = true;

var_dump($shadowObj != $obj);
```

Which results in:

```
bool(true);
```

Both approaches work. But both have disadvantages compared to a non userland implementation. The first one needs CPU for serialization and hashing and the second one needs memory for storing clones. And some classes may not be cloned.

Doesn't PHP track changes at object properties? And does PHP not expose a method to make use of it?

Comment: I think this isn't what you are searching for ? http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.object-comparison.php

Comment: Well for userland objects (as opposed to stdClass objects) I'd use an observer

Comment: How are you defining "Changed" Do you mean a property value reads differently, or that some code has explicitly set a property? Or something else?

Comment: I talk just about the property values. @Rizier123 This deals with two different objects. But I like to check if the *same* object has changed.

Comment: You're trying to implement a "dirty check" on arbitrary objects?

Comment: @deceze Can you explain what you mean with "dirty check"? And what's a "clean check" for you then?

Comment: A "dirty check" is when you need to trigger callbacks on certain changes, but you need to observe those changes from the outside instead of being able to directly hook into the change event itself. In this case you need to figure out what has changed since the last time you looked at the object, whether the object is "dirty" compared to the last state you knew about. You typically do this by keeping a "shadow copy" of the object around and traversing all its properties and comparing the current state to the last shadow copy. That *does* require a bunch of userland code...

Comment: @deceze Okay now I understand. Well what's the advantages/disadvantages in comparision to my solution above? Probably comparing against a shadow copy is more performant then serializing (optionally hashing the serialized data) and compare those 2 strings against each other?

Comment: Performance is likely *worse* for the actual dirty checking itself, but it *may* be better for whatever you're planning to do afterwards. If you can isolate the specific things that changed from those that didn't, you can trigger very selective actions for only the changed items. This may or may not be an advantage for you.

Comment: In this specific case I just need to know *if* the object has changed and not *what exactly* has changed.

Comment: You can force using setters methods instead of assigning values directly. Those methods could track changes.

Comment: You're right but then I can't use e.x. `\stdClass`. And I would have to put logic into "stupid" getter/setter methods. Then I would prefer a shadow copy which I can check with reflection for any changes against the current object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**What you are trying to do?**

You are trying to compare object with itself, after some chain of "unknown" operations to check if the object has changed. If this is true, there are some logical points to observe. At first, if you want to compare object with itself, you've got only two options:

1. Remember the whole object state (for example hash, or just copy whole object)
2. Track changes over time

There is no other logical approach. Comparing memory allocations, real objects, copying objects, comparing hashes, is all in point one. Tracking changes, saving changes inside object, remembering meantime operations, inside point 2.

So in my opinion this question is sort of backing up data questions. In that case there are many, many solutions but none of them are hardcoded inside php as far as I'm concerned. Why?

---

**The answer is simple. PHP guys have got the same problems you've got :).** Because if this would be hardocded inside php, then php should run / use one of those mechanisms (1) or (2).

**In that case every object that you create, and every operation you made should be written somewhere to remember every state / object / something and use them for comparison in the future.**

While you need this solution, almost `~100%` of websites don't. So hardcoding this inside php would made `~100%` of websites work slower and your work faster ;).

---

### PHP hypothetical solution?

The only solution (maybe built in php in the future) I can think of is making some kind of php config flag: `track objects`, and only if this flag is `true`, then run all the php mechanisms of tracking objects states. **But this also mean a huge performance gap.** As all the `ifs` (if tracking, if tracking, if tracking) are also procesor and memory time consuming.

*There is also a problem, what to compare?* You need to compare object with same object, but... Few minutes ago? Few operations ago? No... You must point exactly one place in code, and then point second place in code and compare object in those two places. **So hypothetical auto tracking is... Kind of powerless, as there is no "key" in the *object state ofer time* array.** I mean, even if you got `magic_object_comparer` function, what it should look like?

```
<?php

    function magic_object_comparer() {} // Arguments??
    function magic_object_comparer($object_before, $object_after) {} // you must save object_before somewhere...??
    function magic_object_comparer($object, $miliseconds) {} // How many miliseconds?
    function magic_object_comparer($object, $operations) {} // How many operations? Which operations?


    magic_comparer_start($object);
    // ... Few operations...
    $boolean = magic_comparer_compare_from start($object);
    // Same as own implementation...
?>
```

---

### Sadly, you are left with own implementation...

After all, I would propose to implement some kind of own mechanism for that, and **remember** to use it only there, where you need it. As this mechanism will for sure be time and memory consuming. So think carefully:

1. Which objects you want to compare. Why?
2. When you want to compare them?
3. Does all changes need to be compared?
4. What is the easiest way of saving those states changes?

And after all of that, try to implement it. I see that you've got a huge php knowledge, so I'm pretty sure that you will figure out something. *There are also many comments, and possible ideas in this question and discussion.*

---

**But after all maybe I explained a little why, there is no build in solution, and why there should not be one in the future... :).**

---

### UPDATE

Take a look here: http://www.fluffycat.com/PHP-Design-Patterns/. This is a great resource about php patterns. You should take a look at **adapter**, **decorator** and **observer** patterns, for possible elegant object oriented solutions.

Comment: Thank you very for your thoughts about that "problematic". I guess you hit the point why there isn't a built-in solution. Yes I'm very happy that there are so many other approaches and ideas. I had also some thoughts about using reflection which was not mentioned till now. I definitely will investigate time for tracking objects in PHP and maybe come up with a good library to get it done easily and flexible and *as performant as possible*.

Comment: Thx for accept :). I'm glad that I helped a little. Please, take a look, I updated my answer. The best solution I can think of is overriding every possible method with magic method, which track changes inside object, and immediataly run the original called method. Or "pack" you object into another one that is used for tracking and from the outside is indistinguishable from the original one.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10704365/how-can-i-access-a-container-object-in-php. This question is not related, but the idea of storing one object into another is there. IN that case Foo is the container that is monitoring your object, and bar is an object. Every Bar method must be magically redefined in Foo object. And every object that you want to track, has it own container, and every other does not have it. This is simple and elegant solution I think...

Comment: One more update with a great resource, and possible solutions: adapter, decorator and observer patterns.

Answer (score 2):

While I too am looking for a very fast/faster approach, a variant of method 2 is effectively what I use.  The advantage of this method is that it is (pretty) fast (in comparison to an isset()), depending on object size.  And you don't have to remember to set a `->modified` property each time you change the object.

```
global $shadowcopy; // just a single copy in this simple example.
$thiscopy = (array) $obj; // don't use clone.
if ($thiscopy !== $shadowcopy) {
// it has been modified
// if you want to know if a field has been added use array_diff_key($thiscopy,$shadowcopy);

}
$shadowcopy = $thiscopy; // if you don't modify thiscopy or shadowcopy, it will be a reference, so an array copy won't be triggered.
```

This is basically method 2, but without the clone.  If your property value is another object (vobj), then clone may be necessary (otherwise both references will point to the same object), but then it is worth noting that it is *that* object vobj you want to see if has changed with the above code.  The thing about clone is that it is constructing a second object (similar performance), but if you want to see what values changed, you don't care about the object itself, only the values.  And array casting of an object is very fast (~2x the speed of a boolean cast of a bool) .. well, up until large objects.  Also direct array comparison === is very fast, for arrays under say 100 vals.

I'm pretty sure an even faster method exists...

Answer (score 1):

I can offer you another solution to the problem, In fact to detect "if an object has changed" we can use [observer pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) design principles. May that way should be better for some people who want to get notify about changes in object.

Contracts/ISubject.php

```
<?php

namespace Contracts;

interface ISubject
{
    public function attach($observer): void;
    public function detach($observer): void;
    public function notify(): void;
}
```

Contracts/IObserver.php

```
<?php

namespace Contracts;

interface IObserver
{
    public function update($subject);
}
```

Subject.php

```
class Subject implements ISubject
{
    public $state; // That is detector 

    private $observers;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->observers = new \SplObjectStorage(); // That is php built in object for testing purpose I use SplObjectStorage() to store attach()'ed objects.
    }

    public function attach($observer): void
    {
        echo "Subject: Attached an observer.\n";
        $this->observers->attach($observer);
    }

    public function detach($observer): void
    {
        $this->observers->detach($observer);
        echo "Subject: Detached an observer.\n";
    }

    public function notify(): void
    {
        echo "Subject: Notifying observers...\n";
        foreach ($this->observers as $observer) {
            $observer->update($this);
        }
    }

    public function someYourLogic()
    {
        $this->state = rand(0, 10);
        echo "Subject: My state has just changed to: {$this->state}\n";
        $this->notify();
    }
}
```

Observer1.php | Plus you are able to have as many ConcreteObserver as you want

```
class Observer1 implements IObserver
{
    public function update($subject): void
    {
        if ($subject->state < 5) {
            echo "Observer1: Reacted to the event.\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Clinet.php

```
$subject = new Subject();

$o1 = new Observer1();
$subject->attach($o1);
$subject->someYourLogic();
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in method, I'm afraid. The shadow copy approach is the best way.

A simpler way, if you have control over the class, is to add a `modified` variable:

```
$this->modified = false;
```

When I modify the object in any way, I simply use

```
$obj->modified = true;
```

This way I can later check

```
if($obj->modified){ // Do Something
```

to check if it was modified. Just remember to `unset($obj->modified)` before saving content in a database.

Comment: To be honest this is a very simple "beginner" idea of how to track objects changes. But the question was related to comparing them. What if You change one object, then change it once more and save somewhere else, and once more and want to compare second and third object? I mean, the idea is OK, but it doesn't answer the question. But it can be useful for others, so please do not downvote :).

Comment: @JacekKowalewski Simplicity is the idea. The shadow copy approach is the best of the options.

Comment: Thx for your answer :-). Actually this would answer my question but unfortunately it depends on "on the fly property generation" which you can do in `\stdClass` or you have to include such a public property in each an every class you like to track and have to keep in mind to set the state manually. Shadow copy is not useable if the class has the `__clone()`  method declare as private.

Comment: That's why, as it was suggested above, setters have been invented. stdClass is just a way to easily structure data to pass along, it's not expected to have complex behaviour.

Comment: @TiMESPLiNTER Similar to the shadow copy approach, you could clone just a few variables from your class. e.g., if only `$obj->foo` and `$obj->bar` may be changed, use `$objOld = array($obj->foo, $obj->bar)` Do the same for the object later, then evaluate the `array_diff`.

Answer (score 0):

We can implement it without observer.

For pure php, we can use `$attributes` & `$original` to check what has been modified [check this explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47126952/3256489) if needed.

```
$modifiedValues = [];
foreach($obj->attributes as $column=>$value) {
    if(!array_key_exists($column, $obj->original) || $obj->original[$column] != $value) {
        $modifiedValues[$column] = $value;
    }
}
// then check $modifiedValues if it contains values
```

For Laravel user, we can use the `isDirty()` method. Its usage:

```
$user = App\User::first();
$user->isDirty();          //false
$user->name = "Peter";
$user->isDirty();          //true
```