# Laravel - Get latest changes to object and log them

Tags: php, laravel-5

Is there an easy way to check the changes an object in eloquent went through? 
I'm trying to avoid iterating over the new object and comparing each item with old values.

For example, if I am given:

```
$user = User::find($id);

$user->name = $new_name;
$user->roles()->sync($new_roles);
$user->save();
```

My current solution is to store the `$user` data on `Line 1` into an `$old_user` variable and iterating through the data and checking the values.

Now this might be Ok for this example but in reality that user has a lot more relationships and a lot more data to look through, so I want to know if there's a better way to solving this issue.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Do you need to see if the object has changed or explicitly each change that happened to the object? [See this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28691224/check-if-an-object-has-changed) It goes into some detail about the problem you are describing

Comment: Do you mean multiple update ?

Comment: @JonC basically what I want to do is just pretty much log the changes that a resource goes through. ie (role "admin" was added, name changed: john -> jon, etc)

Comment: I would look at these - [revisionable](https://github.com/VentureCraft/revisionable)  and [versionable](https://github.com/mpociot/versionable) I havent used them myself yet, but they look like what you need