# #attributes vs #original in Laravel when dd()

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

In my Laravel code, when I am processing the records somewhere in the code I am adding new attributes to the array (ex. $obj->newAttr=someContent), later when I dd() the object it shows me two arrays: #attributes and #original, but the newly created attribute show up only in #attributes array.

Here is an example when I dd() the object, I get the #attributes array:

```
  #attributes: array:21 [▼
"field_name" => "229"
"company_name" => "Maya Dairy"
"seeding_rate" => 115
"id" => 11
"property_id" => 71
"acreage" => "73.80"
"status" => "current"
"dairy_crop_variety_id" => 19
"field_weight" => "1432.39"
"moisture" => "67.00"
"starch" => null
"yield_id" => 50
"crop" => "Wheat: <strong>Sumit 515</strong> @ <strong>21.3 T/c</strong>"
"variety" => "Sumit 515"
"planted_at" => "Nov 10, 2016"
"harvested_at" => "May 1, 2017"
"crop_age" => 172
"cropDateLink" => "Harvested: <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editRowCrop" data-id="11" data-method="PATCH"><strong>May 1, 2017</strong> (172 days)</a>"
"yield" => 21.3
"inputs" => ""
"files" => ""
```

and original array:

```
  #original: array:16 [▼
"field_name" => "229"
"company_name" => "Maya Dairy"
"seeding_rate" => 115
"id" => 11
"property_id" => 71
"acreage" => "73.80"
"status" => "current"
"dairy_crop_variety_id" => 19
"field_weight" => "1432.39"
"moisture" => "67.00"
"starch" => null
"yield_id" => 50
"crop" => "Wheat"
"variety" => "Sumit 515"
"planted_at" => "2016-11-10"
"harvested_at" => "2017-05-01"
```

What is the difference between these arrays? And sometimes the newly created attributes are not available in view. I am not sure why. Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

Comment: Original means the original data from the model, before you change them in your controller.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**$attributes** contains the current version of model's attributes. **$original** is supposed to contain, well, the original values of given object, so here you'll find the values that object was created with or the values it was loaded with from the database.

**Note:** the **$original** values are clever enough to be updated with new values once you save the model to the database - the idea is that this array should reflect object's data in the database.

Answer (score 1):

I have some difference I have faced which is:

the `$original` show the pivot attributes if you have many-to-many relationship. However, the `$attributes` doesn't show them.